# C# POS receipt printing issue

Tags: c#, printing

I have written a code in c# by using graphic object to print the receipt on POS printer (EPSON TM-T82 - paper roll : 80 X 297 mm).

sample code is as follow

```
Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
Font regularFont = new Font("Courier New", 8);
Font titleFont = new Font("Courier New", 14);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
float fontHeight = regularFont.GetHeight();
float startX = 10.0F;
float startY = 5.0F;
int offset = 40;
graphic.DrawString("----------------------------------------", regularFont, drawBrush, new PointF(startX, startY+offset), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
string header = "Item Name".PadRight(30) + "Price";
graphic.DrawString(header, regularFont, drawBrush, , new PointF(startX, startY+offset), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
offset = offset + (int)fontHeight;
graphic.DrawString("----------------------------------------", regularFont, drawBrush, new PointF(startX, startY+offset), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

and so on....

Now issue is that while exporting into ".XPS" then it is showing perfect. But while printing on POS printer receipt; it cuts the columns. Meaning to say that it is not printing the full row of string. I tried to fix this issue by passing `RectangleF` in `graphic.DrawString` as per suggestions found over internet but same issue.

Please see the attached screenshots of .XPS and POS receipt

[image]
[image]

Here, in screenshot, the receipt border is marked as black. in .XPS the row is printing perfect (taking full page width) but in POS printer receipt, it is not taking full width (see the white space from cut character to right side border)

If anyone can help me here what exactly i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing your regularFont size a bit smaller to see what it produces. Post results

Comment: I reduced the regular font size (4) and now it prints the receipt without any missing row text but fonts are very small and not even properly readable on printed receipt. I don't want to reduce the font size here. Do you have any other suggestion or solution ?

Comment: If now fits after changing the font size, then the problem is a design one. Two solutions: smaller size or simplify data.
For example you can take the 1@225.00 and put it in two rows.

Comment: Hi Juan, I have modified my original query, Please see the comment again that added just after the new screenshots (with black borders).

Comment: Using the printer driver for a POS printer is wrong in 98% of all cases.  Biggest issue is that it is just too slow and the customer has to wait too long to get his receipt.  And the small stuff, like not having a meaningful page size for paper on a roll.  The one you used isn't wide enough.  Doing it correctly requires writing the print commands directly to the printer, bypassing the driver.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091

Comment: Now i understand your problem. Screenshot made clear what your question is. Here probably you have 3 options. First try to play a bit with Graphics.Clip property. If it doesnt work try to see if you can change printer's paper size , not in windows, but in the printer. IF either of those works, you would have to do something like @HansPassant said and work your way by hand  with print commands to the printer.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant/Juan, I made change as per suggestion but still facing an issue. Please refer the question that i put at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967374/c-sharp-pos-receipt-printing-issue-while-print-commands-directly-to-the-printer

Answer (score 1):

Please use the columnwidth propertie
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
    doc.ColumnWidth = 700;
    doc.PagePadding = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0);

I wish this will help others