# C# POS receipt printing issue while print commands directly to the printer, bypassing the driver

Tags: c#, printing

As per suggestion and provided link by @HansPassant and @Juan from ([C# POS receipt printing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917026/c-sharp-pos-receipt-printing-issue)), i have made the changes in code and now writing the print commands directly to the printer, bypassing the driver (using RawPrinterHelper class). But still there is an issue with the POS printer receipt. It is not taking full width to print the row though the text is not cutting now and it is showing as full text (Screenshot attached)

[image]

But as you can see in screenshot, there are enough space left in between the right side border (Marked black) and where the text ends. If text is large string then it breaks into new line but not printing to the right side.The receipt is printing with max width which is up-to the end of dotted line.Rest right side part is blank.

Also, Can you tell me how to print Rupee Symbol before the price or amount while writing the print commands directly to the printer. Earlier when i was using the printer driver for a POS printer, there in c# code i was writing as following:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("hi-IN"); String.Format(ci, "{0:c}",ProductPrice);
```

But this is not working with print commands directly to the printer. It prints as "?" as you can see just before the price of each item in attached screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are usually hardware jumpers to set paper width -- see if your printer has those and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I went through with the printer manual and found that I am currently using 80 mm width paper roll while the best suitable paper roll is 58 mm in width. 80 mm paper roll can be used but the supported printing will be up to 58 mm only therefore it shows the unused space in between the right side of receipt and where the text ends during the printing. Also,To use the 58 mm paper roll, it is required to install "58-mm width paper guide plate" in the printer.

Comment: Now Can any one tell me that How to print Rupee Symbol before the price or amount while writing the print commands directly to the printer ?